# How to get data from lower time frame on higher time frame using request.security_lower_tf in Pine V5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to display a long signal on the 15 minute chart if (5 minute close) > (5 minute ema). I have to do it using the new *request.security_lower_tf*.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 3):

`request.security_lower_tf()` will return you an array. In your case, it will contain three elements because there are three five minute bars in a fifteen minute bar.

Then you can refer to array elements as you would normally do.

Here is an example for the close price:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

close_5 = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "5", close)

str = ""
len = array.size(close_5)

if (len > 0)
    for i=0 to len-1
        str := str + str.tostring(array.get(close_5, i)) + '\n'

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str)
```

[image]

Comment: The values can be seen on label together. But how to add each values to each variable?

Comment: It’s an array. You can use a for loop.

Comment: Can you please answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75952525/how-to-display-intrabar-values-when-using-lower-time-frame