# How to display Intrabar Values when using Lower Time frame?

Tags: arrays, charts, pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to display last three close values of Intrabar when using Lower Time frame in Pinescript. The code I tried gives is not what I needed.

I am using 15 min chart and I need close of 3 min candle. It generate 5 Intrabar close values in an array. I need only last 2 bar candle close.

My code generates => array of { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } and array of { 6, 7, 8 9, 10 }

The code I need => "1" in one box and "2" in another box

```
indicator('Test W1', overlay=true, shorttitle='Test W1', precision=1)
Close(s) => request.security_lower_tf(s, "3", close)
Close1(s) => request.security_lower_tf(s, "3", close[1])
var table top_boxes = table.new(position.bottom_center, 6, 6, color.black, border_color = color.white)
AR = Close('RELIANCE')
BR = Close1('RELIANCE')
table.cell(top_boxes, 0, 0, text = str.tostring(AR), bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 0), text_color =color.white, height=10, width = 35)
table.cell(top_boxes, 0, 1, text = str.tostring(AR), bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 0), text_color =color.white, height=10, width = 35)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. This will give you the last 2 3 minute closes. You can adjust which close you want by changing the array index number, the only issue is when a new 15 minute candle opens you will get an array out of bounds error until there is a 3 minute candle closed

```
//@version=5
indicator("lower time frame data", overlay = true)

var table top_boxes = table.new(position.bottom_center, 6, 6, color.black, border_color = color.white)

float[] ltfdata = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, '3', close)
float[] newArray = array.new<float>()

if array.size(ltfdata) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(ltfdata) - 1 
        newArray.unshift(ltfdata.get(i))

if barstate.islast
    table.cell(top_boxes, 0, 0, text = str.tostring(newArray.get(1), format.mintick), bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 0), text_color =color.white, height=10, width = 35)
    table.cell(top_boxes, 0, 1, text = str.tostring(newArray.get(2), format.mintick), bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 0), text_color =color.white, height=10, width = 35)
```

Comment: How to avoid the error - array out of bounds.